# phpMyAdmin not accessible from Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./vDocker/php/php.Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./vDocker/.env:/var/www/.env
      - ./vDocker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./vDocker/.env:/var/www/.env
      - ./vDocker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: translive
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: gio123
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./vDocker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network
      
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    depends_on: 
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: gio123
    networks:
      - app-network



#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

I have four services. Three of them work fine and no problem at all, but `phpmyadmin` doesn't work at all.  The thing is all is work fine, database, webserver, but not phpMyAdmin. When I try to go to localhost:8080, it says site can't be reached.  I don't know what's going on. What am I missing?

Comment: What the `phpmyadmin` container's log says? Have you hit `localhost:8080` and check logs?

Comment: I figured it out. It was because phpmyadmin docker has to be set on port 80 on container port.

Comment: What does the nginx config look like? I also have this problem.